# Making Request to django restframework from a deployed django project

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I have a project that was created using django and drf along with jquery's ajax for sending post and get request to my django server url. But I am having an issue when I deploy the project on railway. If I run my project on my localhost or 127.0.0.1:8000 it works totally fine but when I try to make request to my server after deploying it fails and shows a CORs error on my browser dev panel. I tried adding my domain to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS in my settings.py file but that does not fix the problem. I also added my domain to CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST still yet no progress. Please how do I fix this error.

#settings.py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:3000',
'http://127.0.0.1:3000',
'https://my-domain.com',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
'http://localhost:3000',
'https://my-domain.com',
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['https://my-domain.com', 'http://127.0.0.1']

---

#main.js
$.ajax({
url: `https://my-domain.com/api/blogview`,
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",

I tried those codes in my settings.py file yet no progress. And that is how I am making my ajax requests. I also tried order drf endpoints but I still get the same errors on my browser dev panel. These are the errors I got when I run the following command to mimmick a non local server.

-----> manage.py runserver 192.168.86.34:9000

I got this error.

**The Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy header has been ignored, because the URL's origin was untrustworthy. It was defined either in the final response or a redirect. Please deliver the response using the HTTPS protocol. You can also use the 'localhost' origin instead. See https://www.w3.org**

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [django_cors_headers](https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/) package.

Install

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

In `settings.py` add to installed apps

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders",
    ...,
]
```

Also in middleware (*NOTE*: the order here matters. Put it before CommonMiddleware):

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    ...,
]
```

After that put your CORS settings like in this example

```py
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "https://example.com",
    "https://sub.example.com",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
]
```